Is it possible to use OR condition between strings in Cypress 'Should' assertion
I have a scenario where the text String in element could be either 'Value exist in Queue' or 'Value doesn't exist'
So I want to use should assertion to make sure any string of both is rendring properly.
I am trying these options but doesn't work
   cy.get("Attribute").should('include', 'Value exist in Queue' || 'Value doesn't exist')

Is there any work arround to tackle this situation.

I would assume you'd need to use RegEx? .should('include', /(Value exist in Queue|Value doesn't exist/)

There might be a way to do it, but certainly not with || like that. The function is called normally, which means that JS will first calculate the value of the expression X || Y, which is always just X when X is truthy (any non-empty string is truthy). Functions can't change the way their arguments are evaluated.

Use match with a regular expression that matches either string.
cy.get("Attribute").should('match', /Value exist in Queue|Value doesn't exist/)


is there anyway we can pass regex string as variable for example
string1= Value exisst in Queue
how we can use string1 variable in above solution , I am trying below solution
cy.get("Attribute").should('match', /${string1}|Value doesn't exist/)

Use the RegExp constructor: new RegExp(`${string1}|Value doesn't exist`)

You can use a Chai expression oneOf to implement this.
For text in the element
// e.g <div>Value doesn't exist</div>

cy.get('div')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('be.oneOf', ["Value exist in Queue", "Value doesn't exist"])

or for an attribute value
// e.g <p my-attribute="Value doesn't exist"></p>

cy.get('p')
  .should('have.attr', 'my-attribute')
  .and('be.oneOf', ["Value exist in Queue", "Value doesn't exist"])

Here the .and() is operating on the extracted text of the attribute,
i.e .should('have.attr', 'my-attribute') changes the subject from the element to it's attribute.

The selector can take an OR operator, which is just a comma. Instead of testing in the .should() you test in the .get() using :contains().
cy.get("div:contains(Value exist in Queue), div:contains(Value doesn't exist)")
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => {
    if (text === "Value doesn't exist"){
      cy.log('Does not exist')
    }
  })

Or with template
const expectedString  = 'Value exist in Queue'
cy.get(`div:contains(${expectedString}), div:contains(Value doesn't exist)`)

Even shorter, .contains() takes a regex, see contains#Regular-Expression -
cy.contains('div', /Value exist in Queue|Value doesn't exist/)

The .should() assertion is built in to the .get() or .contains().
When no .should() is supplied the default (added by Cypress internally) is .should('exist').

If you prefer to not use a regex,cy.should() allows you to pass in a function. So, we can pass in a function that uses chai's oneOf method.
cy.get('Attribute').should(($attribute) => {
  expect($attribute).to.be.oneOf(['Value exist in Queue', 'Value doesn\'t exist']);
});

Note: I left your cy.get().should() the same in terms of yielded subject, however, you may need to change $attribute to $attribute.text().
